# Не работает анимация в Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть простая анимация https://ektx.000webhostapp.com/firefox-animation/. Во всех браузерах все работает нормально, но в Firefox, при наведении на серое поле круг дергается. Кто-нибудь может подсказать как можно это исправить, чтоб анимация была плавной и в Firefox тоже.

```js
$('#section').on('mousemove', function(e) {
   let y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top - ($(this).height()/2);
   let x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left - ($(this).width()/2);
   x = x * 0.1; y = y * 0.1;
   $('.circle').css({ 'transform': 'translate( '+ x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)' });
});
```

```css
.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  z-index: 1;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #2a3138;
  transition: 1.5s ease-out all;
}

.field {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #7d7f89;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #2a3138;
  transition: 1.5s ease-out all;
}

.field:hover .line {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section" id="section">
  <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="field">
      <span class="line"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.section').on('mousemove', function(e) {
  let y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top - ($(this).height() / 2);
  let x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left - ($(this).width() / 2);
  x = x * 0.1;
  y = y * 0.1;
  $('.circle').css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'translate( ' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)',
    '-moz-transform': 'translate( ' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)',
    'transform': 'translate( ' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)'
  });
});
```

```css
.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  z-index: 1;
}

.circle__section {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #2a3138;
  -webkit-transition: 1.5s ease-out all;
  -moz-transition: 1.5s ease-out all;
  transition: 1.5s ease-out all;
}

.field {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #7d7f89;
}

.line {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -300px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #2a3138;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}

.field:hover .line {
  transform: translateX(300px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section" id="section">
  <div class="circle__section">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <span class="line"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Неа, точно так же дёргается

Comment: Тоже дёргается.

Comment: Пробовал, все равно дергается.

Comment: Вот на всякий случай гифка с демонстрацией https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHQ0T.gif

Comment: Если у .line убрать transition, тогда все нормально. Или если у .line изменять не размер а цвет, например, а transition оставить, тоже работает. Но надо чтоб и размер у .line плавно менялся и круг плавно двигался.

Comment: Да, так работает, но дело в том что у меня таких .field 3 или более на весь экран, а фигура двигается за ними. Поэтому так не очень подходит. Но все равно спасибо.

Comment: Нет, вопрос тот же, непонятно почему фигура дергается при наведении на поле .field и как это исправить. Если в Вашем коде навести на .field она совсем перестает двигаться.

Comment: Не желательно конечно, но если с шириной никак, тогда да, придется так наверное. Спасибо большое.

Comment: На данный момент это просто подчеркивание у элементов и оно зависит просто от ширины элемента.